# Make ContentFlow continuously auto-scroll?

Tags: javascript, html

I have ContentFlow implemented on a site [cookbookfavors.com](http://www.cookbookfavors.com/) and would like to know if there was a way to modify the script so it would automatically scroll through the items? Even if someone could point me to where to look in the code, to add a loop, or something... Thanks!

EDIT: The script: http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php

There is nothing in the documentation that would help... I'd have to modify code.

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide more information. Is it a jQuery plugin? If yes, isn't there anything about this in documentation? Can you provide the link to the doc?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Remember to upvote useful answers, including answers to others' questions. Remember to "check" (accept) the answer that best solves your own questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but the answer is not to "modify the script." Instead, you will write a small helper script to call the ContentFlow's `moveTo` method every "x" seconds. The ContentFlow library itself does not need to be changed.

See the [docs](http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/docu.php) for the library's `moveTo` method.

Your script should do the following:

1. Wait for the page's dom to stabilize
2. Create the ContentFlow instance
3. Start a loop. In the loop, first delay x seconds. Then call the `moveTo` method to move to the next item.

You'll also need to track which is the current item. Ask if you need more info.

**Added** Turns out, there is a [slideshow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/addons.php) AddOn for the ContentFlow library that will handle the auto-scrolling for you. See the [docs](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/addons.php) that show you how to add in an AddOn.

If you don't want the users to see the start/stop slideshow controls, try hiding them via CSS.

Comment: Yeah, any more info would be helpful. 
I'm not sure how I'd track what the current item is...

Comment: Show us your current code that uses ContentFlow and I'll suggest some updates to it.

Comment: It's extremely simple:

            var myNewFlow = new ContentFlow('contentFlow', { visibleItems: 2, scrollInFrom: 4, maxItemHeight: 300, onclickActiveItem: null } ) ;

Comment: Try adding the slideshow addon using the links in my amended answer. Ask if you have further questions.

Comment: Remember to "check" (accept) this answer if it solves your question.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in a very simple way, no need for a slideshow AddOn. Here's a code sample to get you started:

```
var myCf = new ContentFlow('myContentFlow', {
    circularFlow: true,
    loadingTimeout: 60000
});

function go_to_next_and_wait() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myCf.moveTo('right');
        go_to_next_and_wait();
    }, 5000); // 5000ms = 5 seconds
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    go_to_next_and_wait();
});
```

Comment: This works fine for me. I recommended this method for auto-scroll.